# Basic workflow for setting up mysql database online

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'd like to set up a Mysql database online. I've been trying to find information on this online, but I haven't been able to find a good summary of the whole process. I have very limited experience with webhosting in general, so would really appreciate any pointers.

My questions would be:
- do you needed a dedicated mysql server online, or can I just set one up on my webspace (I have a website that I use for random stuff)
- how do I go about setting up a database on my webspace (if possible)

So far I've uploaded phpMyAdmin to my site, and the start screen loads fine, but I'm stumped for user and password. Do I need to enter my webspace ftp user and password here? Or my mysql user and password (which I'd find weird since I have not actually set up any mysql webspace yet). Or do I need to configure phpMyAdmin for a specific user and password?

So yeah, very basic stuff really... :)

Thanks!
Dave

Comment: [What kind of questions can I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: You are more likely to get a solid answer to this question on serverfault.com than you are here.  There are MANY cheap hosting companies that offer both "webspace" as you put it, MySQL service, and phpMyAdmin as part of what they do.

Comment: Do you want to install a daemon or just create a new database?